# Add new line with previous line's indentation

Tags: sed, yaml, indentation

I'm struggling since a moment now to update some yaml files by adding an element in a new line with sed.

The sed command (or another linux command) must match a string (`image:` or `- image:`), add a new element on a new line with the same indentation as previous line.

The thing is that the new line must be exactly just under the string `image:` and not under `- image:`.

Example: When the sed matches the string `image`, it adds the new line with correct indentation (just above `image`)

```yaml
kind: DaemonSet
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: calico-node
spec:
  template:    
    spec:      
      containers:        
        - name: calico-node
          image: myimage    
          imagePullSecret: mysecret
...
```

Example 2: when the sed matches the string `- image`, it adds the new line with correct indentation (just above `image` and not `-`):

```yaml
kind: DaemonSet
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: calico-node
spec:
  template:    
    spec:      
      containers:
      - image: myimage    
        imagePullSecret: mysecret
...
```

What is not wanted is

```yaml
kind: DaemonSet
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: calico-node
spec:
  template:    
    spec:      
      containers:
      - image: myimage    
      imagePullSecret: mysecret
```

I already tried the `yq` command to deal with this but it's a gigantic pain...

I found this code in another thread but it doesn't  work when matching the `- image` string.

```sh
sed '/^ *image: .*/ { G; s/^\( *\)image: .*/&\1imagePullSecret: mysecret/; }' sed.yaml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this awk:

```
awk '/^[[:space:]-]*image/{ split($0,arr,/image.*/) 
                           gsub(/-/," ", arr[1])
                           rep=arr[1]
                           print $0}
                       rep{ printf "%s%s\n", rep, "imagePullSecret: mysecret"
                       rep=""
                       next} 1' file
```

Comment: You need to unset rep after printing that line. This only works if the image is on the last line of the file.

Comment: Worked prefectly as soon as I replace image by image: 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I don't condone the use of `sed` to parse `yaml`, but if you really want to do that, you could try something like:

```
$ nl='                                                                                      
'
$ printf '   image:\n     - image:\n' | 
    sed -e "s/\(^\( *\)image:\)/\1\\$nl\2inserted text/" \
    -e "s/\(^\( *\)- image:\)/\1\\$nl\2  inserted text/"
   image:
   inserted text
     - image:
       inserted text
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```sh
sed '
    /^( *)image: .*/   {p; s//\1imagePullSecret: mysecret/; }
    /^( *)- image: .*/ {p; s//\1  imagePullSecret: mysecret/; }
' sed.yaml
```

The empty pattern in `s//replacement/` reuses the most-recently used pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk to utilise gensub:

```
awk '/image: /{ str=$0 } str { print;str1=gensub(/(^.*)(image:.*$)/,"\\1imagePullSecret: mysecret",str);sub("-"," ",str1);print str1;del str;next }1' file
```

Explantion:

```
awk '/image: /{ # Process the image tag
                 str=$0 # Set a variable str equal to the line
              } 
          str { # Process when we have a str set
                 print; # Print the current line
                 str1=gensub(/(^.*)(image:.*$)/,"\\1imagePullSecret: mysecret",str); # Split the line into two sections and set str1 to the first section (get the leading spaces) and then the text we want to add.
                 sub("-"," ",str1); # Replace any - in the text with a space
                 print str1; # Print the new line
                 del str; # Remove the str variable
                 next # Skip to the next line
               }1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Yq v4 doesn't yet support maps for addition, but you could convert to JSON, use jq, and then convert back to YAML:

```sh
yq --tojson eval infile.yaml \
    | jq '.spec.template.spec.containers[0] += {imagePullSecret: "mysecret"}' \
    | yq eval -prettyPrint
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/(-( ))?image:.*/{p;s//\2\2imagePullSecret: mySecret/}' file
```

Match on `image:.*` with an optional `-`  prepended.

Print the current line.

Replace the match by `imagePullSecret: mySecret` with the optional space following the  `-` prepended twice.